# Backreference Bug in Notepad++ Non-Consecutive Line Duplication Finder Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, backreference

There seems to be a bug in the Notepad++ find/replace behaviour when using a backreference to find duplicate lines that may not necessarily be consecutive. I'm wondering if anyone knows what the issue could be with the regex or if they know why the regex engine might be bugging out?

## Details

I wanted to use a regex to find duplicate lines in Notepad++. The duplicates needn't necessarily be contiguous i.e. on consecutive lines, there can be lines in between. I started with this post:

https://medium.com/@heitorhherzog/compare-sort-and-delete-duplicate-lines-in-notepad-2d1938ed7009

But realised that the regex mentioned there only checks for contiguous duplicates. So I wrote my own regex:

```
^(.+)$(?:(?:\s|.)+)^(\1)$
```

The above basically captures something on a whole line, then matches a load of stuff in between, then captures the same thing about on a line.

### What's wrong

The regex works, but only sometimes. I can't figure out the pattern. I've whittled it down to this so far. If I do a "Replace All" on the replacement pattern `\1\2` then the "replace all" leaves me with just line 3, which is "elative backreferences32". This is wrong:

```
dasfdasfdsfasdfasdfadsfasdf
elative backreferenceswe
elative backreferences32
elative backreferencesd
elative backreferencdesdfdasdfsdafsd
asfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfdsaasdfas
asdfasdfafds  asdfasfdsafasd asdfdasfsd
elative backreferencessfhdfg
x
y
x
```

But if I delete *any* line from that file, then only the consecutive lines `x` then `y` then `x` are replaced by a single line `xx` as I'd expect.

## Notes

- I'd like to keep this question focused mostly on why the regex is
  bugging out. Suggestions about alternative ways to find duplicate
  lines are of course good but the main reason I'm asking this is to
  figure out what's going on with the regex and Notepad++.
- I don't really need the replace part of this, just the find, I was just using the replace to try to figure out what groups were being captured in an attempt to debug this
- The find behaviour is also buggy. I noticed this first actually. It first finds the match I'm actually looking for, and then if I click "Find Next" again, it highlights all the text.

## Hypotheses

- There is a bug in Notepad++ v7.8.4 64 bit. I just updated today so maybe they haven't caught it yet.
- Does the in-between part of the match, `(?:(?:\s|.)+)`, maybe cycle
  around past the end of file character and loop right back to the
  original match? If so, I'd say that's still a bug, because AFAIK a
  regex should only consume each character once.
- I thought there might be a limit to the number of characters in the file, but I disproved this hypothesis by playing around with the file, adding characters here and there. Two files with the same number of lines and the same number of characters can behave differently: one with buggy behaviour, one without.

## Screenshots

### Before

[image: Before Replace All]

### After Without Matches Newline (The intended configuration)

[image: After Replace All]

### After With Matches Newline (for Experimentation)

[image: After With Matches Newline]

Comment: I don't see the behaviour you describe. It works fine for me, the first lines stay and the 3 last become `xx` when I press `Replace All` Could you add a screen capture?

Comment: Weird.... Hang on I'll capture the screen. @Toto it could be a version issue. I updated today.

Comment: For future readers. The below workaround works, but this still appears to be a bug of the Notepad++ regex engine. It seems that the OR operator is a bit unstable and is probably the cause of the trouble. I believe the OR operator was added later than other features so maybe that's why it's less stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?:\s|.)` should be avoid as it causes unexpected behaviour, I suggest using `[\s\S]` instead:

- Find what: `^(.+)$[\s\S]+?^(\1)$`
- Replace with: `$1$2`

Comment: @ColmBhandal: Try to change  `(?:(?:\s|.)+)`    into `[\s\S]+?`